# Как получить все свойства объекта?

Tags: php

вот объект

```
object(stdClass)#2258 (2) { 
    ["menus"]=> object(stdClass)#2253 (5) { 
        ["menu0"]=> object(stdClass)#2250 (1) { 
            ["title"]=> "menu0"} 
        ["menu1"]=> object(stdClass)#2254 (1) { 
            ["title"]=> "menu1" } 
        ["menu2"]=> object(stdClass)#2255 (1) { 
            ["title"]=> "menu2" } 
        ["menu3"]=> object(stdClass)#2256 (1) {
            ["title"]=> "menu3" } 
        ["menu4"]=> object(stdClass)#2257 (1) { 
            ["title"]=> "menu3"  }
    } 
    ["extra-1"]=> object(stdClass)#2260 (1) { 
        ["munu0"]=> object(stdClass)#2259 (9) { 
            ["title"]=> string(32) "extra-1 munu0"  } 
    } 
    ["extra-2"]=> object(stdClass)#2260 (1) { 
        ["munu0"]=> object(stdClass)#2259 (9) { 
            ["title"]=> string(32) "extra-2 munu0"  } 
    } 
    ["extra-3"]=> object(stdClass)#2260 (1) { 
        ["munu0"]=> object(stdClass)#2259 (9) { 
            ["title"]=> string(32) "extra-3 munu0"  } 
    } 
    ["extra-4"]=> object(stdClass)#2260 (1) { 
        ["munu0"]=> object(stdClass)#2259 (9) { 
            ["title"]=> string(32) "extra-4 munu0"  } 
    } 
}
```

как можно получить все свойства extra-* учитывая что их может не быть вообще и быть бесконечно много.  Вообще желательно получить свойства menu0 свойств extra-*

Comment: Вы заметили, что у вас там `munu` вместо `menu`? Так можно долго пытаться.

Comment: Преобразовать в JSON, потом - в массив, а дальше цикл или функции работы с массивами. Хотя похоже что ваш объект получен из JSON, так что вам нужно просто правильно использовать `json_decode`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если этот объект получился из JSON, то да, как пишут другие нужно просто правильно указать второй параметр у [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

`json_decode($value,false)` - возвращает stdObject
`json_decode($value,true)` - возвращает массив

Если же приходится работать именно с объектом, то есть два варианта:
1. Преобразовать в json и обратно уже в массив `json_decode(json_encode($object),true)`
2. Воспользоваться функцией [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-object-vars.php) и получить массив свойств объекта

При любых раскладах получаем массив, проходим циклом и находим нужные ключи и их значения

Пример с JSON:

```
//Если у нас именно объект а не готовый JSON
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object),true)

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    //вместо strpos можно и регуляркой
    if (strpos($key,'extra') ===  0 && isset($value['menu0']['title'])) {
        echo $value['menu0']['title'].'<br/>';
    }   
}
```

Пример с использованием get_object_vars:

```
$objectVars = get_object_vars($object);
foreach ($objectVars as $key => $value) {
    //вместо strpos можно и регуляркой
    if (strpos($key,'extra') ===  0 && isset($value->menu0->title)) {
        echo $value->menu0->title.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы основную проблему не объяснили. Массивом ли это делать или объектом разницы нет мне надо выбрать все значения с колючем extra-* то есть все кроме menus.

Comment: Хм, вообще-то уяснил))) В обоих примерах в коде присутствует `strpos($key,'extra') ===  0` оно и найдет Вам extra,extra-1, extra-2, extra_3 и прочие ключи начинающиеся с extra, для более точных случаев используйте регулярные выражения

Comment: Хорошо я вот этим я выяснил `strpos($key,'extra') === 0` что есть но как мне дальше получить их получить что бы работать ну к примеру с тем же foreach ?

Comment: Посмотрите на приведенный выше код внимательнее, в указанных примерах у нас уже есть цикл где в качестве $key у нас ключи ['menus','extra-0','extra-1' .... 'extra-n'] а в качестве $value значения по этим ключам. Строка `if (strpos($key,'extra') ===  0 && isset($value->menu0-title)` проверяет начинается ли ключ с экстра и есть ли (для примера для этого ключа menu0->title и если есть, то этот title выводится

Comment: Все получилось большое спасибо